# Form is only outputting the errors

Tags: php, html

I have a simple contact form where clients will put their referrals although upon submission of the form it takes me to the process page which is fine cause the thank you page is implemented the.  but upon submission it simply takes me to the posses page and not the thank you page. I cannot find the issue and could use some help from you guys

The form:

```
 <form action="includes/mail.php" method="post">
<table background="images/sequestrationreferral.jpg" height="408px" width="740px">
<tr>
<td width="80px" height="50px"><label>Name:</label></td>
<td><input class="input" type="text" name="name" width="225px" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="80px" height="50px"><label>Email Address:</label></td>
<td><input class="input" type="text" name="email" width="225px" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="80px" height="120px"><label>Referals:</label></td>
<td><textarea class="input" name="referals" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea><br /><br />Please use one per row?</td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send referals" class="btn" /></td>
</table>
</form>
```

The Process page:

```
<?
/* Edit these preferences to suit your needs */

  $mailto = 'marketing@loanro.co.za'; // insert the email address you want the form sent to
    $returnpage = '../thanks.php'; // insert the name of the page/location you want the user to be returned to
    $sitename = '[Loanro]'; // insert the site name here, it will appear in the subject of your email

/* Do not edit below this line unless you know what you're doing */

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'] ;
  $referals = stripslashes($_POST['referals']);

    if (!$name) {
        print("<strong>Error:</strong> Please provide your name.<br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Back</a>");
         exit;
    }
    if (!$email) {
        print("<strong>Error:</strong> Please provide an email address.<br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Back</a>");
         exit;
    }
    if (!$referals) {
        print("<strong>Error:</strong> Please provide your enquiry details.<br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Back</a>");
         exit;
    }
    if (!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([-_\.]?[a-z0-9])+@[a-z0-9]+([-_\.]?[a-z0-9])+\.[a-z]{2,4}", $email)){
    print("<strong>Error:</strong> this email address is not in a valid format.<br/><br/><a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Back</a>");
         exit;
    }   

  $message = "\n$name submitted the following message:\n\n$enquiry\n\nTheir contact details are as follows:\n\nName: $name\nEmail Address: $email\n\n";

  mail($mailto, "$sitename Referal from $name", $message, "From: $email");
    header("Location: " . $returnpage);
?>
```

And the Thank you page:

```
<article class="art-post art-article">


                <div class="art-postcontent art-postcontent-0 clearfix"><div class="art-content-layout layout-item-0">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="art-content-layout-wrapper layout-item-4">
<div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
    <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-5" style="width: 75%" >
<p>Thank you for contacting up, we will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>


    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



</article>
```

Comment: try "ob_end_clean();" before "header()"

Comment: I think the problem is because there is problem in process page.what error you get in process page?

Comment: If it is outputting errors, it's seems ok to not display thank you page... But you should not display anything before an header

Comment: @tinyByte - what about `ob_start();` at first? I think it's needed too if we want to use `ob_end_clean();`

Comment: Yes it only displays the output errors in the "if" statments and its not routing to the thanks.php

Comment: I think the problem is with short php tags!

Comment: @ tinyByte Short php tags was the problem thanks to all....

Comment: @tinyByte - please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @MauriceBotha - please accept tinyByte's answer if you think it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks okay.
The Location header could fail because of 2 reasons:

1. your script yust did some outputs befor sending the header (could be an error, or simple a unseen sign befor your `<?php`
2. the Location header should be user with absolut urls, maybe there is a problem with your relative path.

You could replace you location header with:

```
$returnurl = "http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]
           . ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]!=80?":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]:"")
           . dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "/"
           . $returnpage;
header("Location: " . $returnurl);
```

And to make a better difference between success and input errors you coul change your script to:

```
<?
/* Edit these preferences to suit your needs */

  $mailto = 'marketing@loanro.co.za'; // insert the email address you want the form sent to
    $returnpage = '../thanks.php'; // insert the name of the page/location you want the user to be returned to
    $sitename = '[Loanro]'; // insert the site name here, it will appear in the subject of your email

/* Do not edit below this line unless you know what you're doing */

  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'] ;
  $referals = stripslashes($_POST['referals']);

  $errors = array();
  if (!$name)      $errors[] = "Please provide your name.";
  if (!$email)     $errors[] = "Please provide an email address.";
  if (!$referals)  $errors[] = "Please provide your enquiry details.";
  if (!eregi("^[a-z0-9]+([-_\.]?[a-z0-9])+@[a-z0-9]+([-_\.]?[a-z0-9])+\.[a-z]{2,4}", $email)) {
    $errors[] = "this email address is not in a valid format.";
  }   

  if(count($errors) == 0)
  {
    $message = "\n$name submitted the following message:\n\n$enquiry\n\nTheir contact details are as follows:\n\nName: $name\nEmail Address: $email\n\n";

    mail($mailto, "$sitename Referal from $name", $message, "From: $email");
    $returnurl = "http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"]
               . ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]!=80?":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"]:"")
               . dirname($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]) . "/"
               . $returnpage;
    header("Location: " . $returnurl);
  }
  else
  {
    echo "<strong>Errors:</strong>";
    echo "<ul><li>".implode("</li>\n<li>",$errors)."</li></ul>";
    echo "<a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>Back</a>";
  }
?>
```

If this still does not work, stop using Location an do:

```
readfile($returnpage);
```

instead.

by the way, your code examples don`t look like full html pages, they should be at least surrounded with

```
<html>
  <body>
  // Your content
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you webserver is configured to show warnings (or you can enable them for development), please provide them.

It appears that your `header()` call doesn't work. This usually is the case if you have **any** kind of output before this call. This can be any whitespace (space, newline, etc.) before the beginning `<?` tag of the php script or it may even be an invisible character like an [UTF-BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). If you use an editor like Notepad++ you can check if the file is saved in UTF encoding and ensure it is without BOM.

Comment: +1 you pointed to very good points that would cause such problems.

Answer (score 1):

Short `php` (ie `<?,?>` , `<?= 'something' ?>`) tags sometimes make problems. I always put full php tags (`<?php ?>` , `<?php echo 'something' ?>`)

And also It's better to put `ob_start();` before any output and `ob_end_clean();` before redirecting.

cheers